# Merge rows based on one column SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I currently have a `user_addresses` table:

```
id | name | address_type | address
---+------+--------------+----------
 1 | John | HOME         | home addr
 1 | John | MAIL         | mail addr
 2 | Bill | HOME         | home addr
 3 | Rick | HOME         | home addr
 3 | Rick | MAIL         | mail addr
```

I want to build a new view that uses the data from the `user_addresses` table. When `address_type=MAIL`, it should use their mail address in the `address` field. Otherwise it uses their `home` address:

```
id | name | address_type | address   | data from other tables
---+------+--------------+-----------+-----------------------
 1 | John | MAIL         | mail addr |
 2 | Bill | HOME         | home addr |
 3 | Rick | MAIL         | mail addr |
```

I'm currently flattening the `user_addresses` table so users are one row and they have home/mail addresses in their own columns. Then I'm selecting from this new flattened view and doing a case statement:

`case when mail_address is not null then mail_address else home_address end`

Should I be using `max(case when)`, a union/minus, or something else?? What is the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: What happened when you tried each of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason not to use PIVOT?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e6fd/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("id" int, "name" varchar2(4), "address_type" varchar2(4), "address" varchar2(9))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("id", "name", "address_type", "address")
         VALUES (1, 'John', 'HOME', 'home addr')
    INTO t ("id", "name", "address_type", "address")
         VALUES (1, 'John', 'MAIL', 'mail addr')
    INTO t ("id", "name", "address_type", "address")
         VALUES (2, 'Bill', 'HOME', 'home addr')
    INTO t ("id", "name", "address_type", "address")
         VALUES (3, 'Rick', 'HOME', 'home addr')
    INTO t ("id", "name", "address_type", "address")
         VALUES (3, 'Rick', 'MAIL', 'mail addr')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with flat as (
  select * from t 
  pivot(
    max("address") 
    for "address_type" in ('HOME' as home,'MAIL' as mail)
  )
 )
 select "id","name",coalesce(mail, home) as address 
 from flat
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e6fd/6/0)**:

```
| id | name |   ADDRESS |
|----|------|-----------|
|  2 | Bill | home addr |
|  3 | Rick | mail addr |
|  1 | John | mail addr |
```

p.s. Disregard double-quoted identifiers - too lazy to fix sqlfiddle's text-to-ddl parser output :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to take all ids with the "mail" record and then all the "home" record for all ids with no "mail" record:

```
select ua.*
from user_addresses us
where address_type = 'MAIL'
union all
select ua.*
from user_addresses ua
where address_type = 'HOME' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_addresses ua2
                  where ua2.id = ua.id and ua2.address_type = 'MAIL'
                 );
```

Another method is to prioritize the rows using `row_number()`:

```
select ua.*
from (select ua.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (case when address_type = 'MAIL' then 1 else 2 end)) as seqnum
      from user_addresses ua
     ) ua
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use window functions:

```
 create or replace view v
as 
  with cte as
    (
      select id , name , address_type , address,
             row_number() over(partition by id order by address_type desc) rn
      from your_table       
    )
    select id , name , address_type , address from cte where rn=1;
```